# why my css won't work here

Tags: html, css

the code wont to work can you help me or told me why it won't to style my html.
    i tried everything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><br />
 <title>twitter</title>
  <style>
 body  background-color: #bbbbbb; 
   #content
{ border: 1px solid #bbbbbb; width: 80%; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px margin: 0 auto; }
 #site_name { border-bottom: 3px soild #bbbbbb; padding-bottom:20px; } 
 footer { text-align:center; }
  </style>
</head>

<body> <br />
<br />
<div id="content"> 
<h1 id="site_name">tweet me</h1>
 <footer> <h6>All rights reserved</h6> 
 </footer> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Comment if down-vote!

Comment: What do you expect from this CSS ? What "doesn't work" ?

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors in this document, learning CSS would be a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CORRECTIONS MADE:**

- `body  background-color: #bbbbbb;` changed to `body {background-color: #bbbbbb; }`
- `padding: 20px margin: 0 auto;`  missed a semi colon in between. Changed to `padding: 20px; margin: 0 auto;`
- Instead of `footer { text-align:center;  }`, the H6 tag is given center alignment as `h6 { text-align:center;  }`

Check this working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>twitter</title>
 <style>
  body {background-color: #bbbbbb; }
   #content
    { 
       border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
       width: 80%;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       padding: 20px;
       margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #site_name 
    { 
       border-bottom: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
       padding-bottom:20px;
    } 
 h6 { text-align:center; }
  </style>
</head>

<body> 
<br />
<br />
<div id="content"> 
<h1 id="site_name">tweet me</h1>
 <footer> <h6>All rights reserved</h6> 
 </footer> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `:` after `footer` and turn `soild` into `solid`

Answer (score 4):

```
 <style>
   background-color: #bbbbbb; 
   ...
```

you have defined a property outside a selector. You should enclose this property inside a rule.
Probably this leads to a parsing error of remaining rules so the style is not applied. If you use a validator you could detect this kind of issues.

Also here

```
border-bottom: 3px soild #bbbbbb;
```

you mistyped `solid`

Comment: ok fix my code how can i style it

Comment: is it yours a question or is it a statement?

Answer (score -1):

```
   #content
    { 
       border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
       width: 80%;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       padding: 20px;
       margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #site_name 
    { 
       border-bottom: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
       padding-bottom:20px;
    } 
 h6 { text-align:center; }
```

add above code in your css 
and try hope it will help ful to you